# ngx-loading - Problem with this.loading = false

Tags: angular, loading, angular9, ngx-loading

I am using ngx-loading in my HTML, this.loading = true works fine with sendMail() function but for some reason, after the success message the loader doesn't disappear as if it doesn't recognize this.loading = false. Any help would be appreciated as I don't understand what is wrong here.

```
<div class="card-reinfort"> <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '3px' }"></ngx-loading></div>
```

And component:

```
@Component({
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
selector: 'ma-reinforcement',
templateUrl: './reinforcement.component.html'
})
export class ReinforcementComponent {
loading = false;
reinforcementList$: Observable<Array>;
@ViewChild(ReinforcementTableComponent, { static: false }) table: 
ReinforcementTableComponent;

constructor(private readonly reinforcementService: ReinforcementService, private readonly 
toastrService: ToastrService) {
this.reinforcementList$ = this.reinforcementService.getAll();
}

onSaveEvent(reinforcementItem: ReinforcementItem): void {
this.reinforcementList$ = this.reinforcementService.save(reinforcementItem);
}

sendMail(): void {
this.loading = true;
this.reinforcementService.sendMail('Export du renfort sur la ligne de caisse', 'Message')
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.toastrService.success('L\export a bien été envoyé', 'Success');
    },
        error => {
            this.toastrService.error('L\'email n\'a pas été envoyé', 'Erreur');
        }
    );

    }
   }
```

Comment: Is `this.toastrService.success` working?

Comment: Yes, it does work. The message shows but ngx-loading is still on true

Answer (score 0):

Add `*ngIf="loading"` to show it only when `loading` is true.

Try like this:

```
<ngx-loading *ngIf="loading" [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '3px' }"></ngx-loading>
```

Comment: Hello @adrita-sharma, I tried that already but it doesn't fix the problem, the loader is still showing

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: justf fixed this by adding this.ref.detectChanges(); after this.loading = false. For some reason doesn't work with changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and even changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding this.ref.detectChanges(); after this.loading = false